# Как на странице сайта определить ссылку по фрагменту текста и без учёта регистра текста?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Имеется код со следующим сценарием:

1. Поиск ссылок на странице
2. Если текст содержит **"программа на C#"**, то код нажимает на ссылку.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
    List<IWebElement> Element = 
        Browser.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#tabnews_newsc a")).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < Element.Count; i++ )
    {
        String s = Element[i].Text;                

        if (s.Contains("программа на C#")) // если текст СОДЕРЖИТ
        {
            Element[i].Click(); // КЛИК по новости, которая СОДЕРЖИТ искомый текст
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:**

Как сделать, чтобы поиск осуществлялся без учёта регистра текста для поиска?

Т.е. если текст содержит "программа на C#", то переход осуществляется, а если текст содержит "Программа на C#" (слово "Программа" с большой буквы "П" ), то перехода по ссылке не происходит.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (s.ToLower().Contains("программа на c#"))
```

Так можно

Answer (score 1):

Этот код должен сработать так как тебе нужно:

```
var link= Browser.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'программа на C#')]"));

if (link!= null) link.Click();
```

а весь свой код удали :)